# Why does \d not match digits when using awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I'm finding a behaviour I can't really explain with awk. Maybe it's a silly mistake but I can't figure it out.

I have a file called files with some random filenames.

```
$ cat -e files
3beds.txt$
file4.txt$
file3.txt$
dedo$
file5.txt$
texto5.txt$
metoo.txt$
34lions$
texto2.txt$
file1.txt$
7hello$
summer$
missing$
hello.mundo$
helloWorld.txt$
texto3$
awkvars$
texto4$
yes$
file2.txt$
```

I want to print only the filenames containing digits. I used the command:

```
awk '/\d/{print $0}' files
```

But my result was:

```
$ awk '/\d/{print $0}' files
3beds.txt
dedo
hello.mundo
helloWorld.txt
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone can explain to me why those lines are being printed. Thank you!

Comment: Try something like: `awk '/[0-9]/' file` OR with grep `grep '\d' file`?

Comment: if I do 
awk '/[0-9]/' files
I get the desired behaviour, but why it does not work with /\d/?

Comment: See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Comment: This is not a silly mistake considering there are lots of online resources which state, incorrectly, you can use `\d` i.e. https://opensource.com/article/19/11/how-regular-expressions-awk

Answer (score 9):

#### Clue: the four lines that matched were the four lines that contained "d".

So, clearly `\d` was being interpreted as a literal "d".

Why? Because awk's regex syntax is `POSIX Extended Regular Expressions`, not the `Perl`, `PCRE` or `Ecma` you might be used to. So `\d` does not stand for "digit" as you were expecting. You ended up using a backslash escape to force a literal "d".

The equivalent for `\d` in awk depends on the semantics you want[1]. `[0-9]` will match only the ten ASCII digits. You could also use the [POSIX character class for digit inside a POSIX Bracket Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class), `[[:digit:]]`:

> When used on strings with non-ASCII characters, the [:digit:] class may include digits in other scripts, depending on the locale.

My quotations are from [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), which has a wealth of info on the many syntaxes. [This page](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816) took info from that page and turned it into a convenient table that compares 15 of them in great detail.

---

[1]: Even for regex engines that support the shorthand `\d`, the semantics can differ:

> Since certain character classes are used often, a series of shorthand character classes are available. \d is short for [0-9]. In most flavors that support Unicode, \d includes all digits from all scripts. Notable exceptions are Java, JavaScript, and PCRE. These Unicode flavors match only ASCII digits with \d.

Comment: *It has no equivalent for `\d`* - what about `[[:digit:]]`? If it is no equivalent explain why.

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`, if you `want to print only the lines containing digits`, you can use this regexp instead:

```
awk '/[[:digit:]]/' file
3beds.txt$
file4.txt$
file3.txt$
file5.txt$
texto5.txt$
34lions$
texto2.txt$
file1.txt$
7hello$
texto3$
texto4$
file2.txt$
```

Comment: Why are using `[[:digit:]]+` rather than just `[[:digit:]]`?